# setlocale() in php, the ç isn't working in date names like terça-feira, is just showing �

Tags: php, strftime, setlocale

Yes, I've already changed the charset a lot of times.
If I set the charset to ISO-8859 it shows ç but the accents doesn't and if I change the charset to UTF-8 the ç which is generated turns into � but the accents are showed.
Here is the code

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ptb");
    echo "Dia da semana: ".strftime("%A", time());
?>
```

Comment: Have you changed both the header charset and the file chartset? If you have an IDE, there's a place where you choose the encoding of the file.